# JS to Meteor events

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, meteor

I have this function that should implement a dropdown list on click event.
The trouble is that I need to implement it in Meteor and really have no idea how to implement the find('a').
I have tried the function also in onCreated() but without any effect.

```
$("#sidebar-menu").find('a').on('click', function(ev) {

    var $li = $(this).parent();
    console.log($li);

    if ($li.is('.active')) {
        $li.removeClass('active active-sm');
        $('ul:first', $li).slideUp(function() {
            setContentHeight();
            console.log("was active")
        });
    } else {
        // prevent closing menu if we are on child menu
        console.log("on else loop")
        if (!$li.parent().is('.child_menu')) {
            $("#sidebar-menu").find('li').removeClass('active active-sm');
            $("#sidebar-menu").find('li ul').slideUp();
        }

        $li.addClass('active');
        console.log("now is active")
        $('ul:first', $li).slideDown(function() {
            console.log("sliding menu")
            setContentHeight();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using blaze or react?

Comment: If you are using Blaze, you should probably use `onRendered` instead of `onCreated` if you need to access DOM elements.

Comment: I am using React. Indeed I had used onCreated and after switching to onRendered it really works as expected. Thanks a lot.